# THREE.JS Anti-Alias not working in multi-scene set-up

Tags: three.js, antialiasing

What's the trick for getting anti-aliasing to work properly on smaller scenes - which are overlaid on top of big scenes?

Check out this fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/j974zmq0/6/

When you tap on any of the cubes you see there a new smaller "detailsScene" opens up on top of the main scene - and the cube in that "detailsScene" is not looking good. (It may not look all that bad here, but trust me, in my real project I'm loading a ".glb" model and it looks really terrible there. And it's not the model that's off. I know that because when I load it into my main scene it looks 100% perfect. Unless I have to re-load it for some reason into this smaller scene...?)

Otherwise I'm pretty sure I set the renderer for this smaller scene the right way, using:

```
detailsRenderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
```

(You'll find that bit on line 192 in the JS of the fiddle code.)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-aliasing is working fine. The scene is just a bit blurred, because the canvas is scaled up while the renderer renders on a smaller size. You should always set the size of the renderer, such that it matches the canvas size. Just passing the canvas element to the renderer is obviously not enough in order to let the renderer know on which size it should render the scene.

```js
detailsRenderer.setSize(detailsCanvas.offsetWidth, detailsCanvas.offsetHeight);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sg3fn0tk/